# Stack level too deep using Citrus for Parsing Expression Grammar

Tags: ruby, recursion, grammar, peg, treetop

I'm trying to process what will eventually be Boolean logic using a grammar in Treetop-like Citrus for Ruby. I'm getting a recursion issue, but I'm unclear on exactly why. Here's the text I'm trying to process (it should have a newline at the very end):

```
COMMANDWORD # MYCOMMENT
```

Here's my Citrus grammar (intended to deal with more advanced stuff):

```
grammar Grammar
  rule commandset
    command+
  end

  rule command
    identifier command_detail* comment_to_eol* "\n"
  end

  rule command_detail
    assign_expr | expr
  end

  rule assign_expr
    identifier ":=" expr
  end

  rule expr
    # Stack overflow
    or_expr | gtor_expr
    # No problem!
    # or_expr
  end

  rule or_expr
    # Temporarily match everything except a comment...
    [^#]+
    # What I think will be correct in the future...
    # gtor_expr "OR" expr
  end

  rule gtor_expr
    and_expr | gtand_expr
  end

  rule and_expr
    gtand_expr "AND" gtor_expr
  end

  rule gtand_expr
    not_expr | gtnot_expr
  end

  rule not_expr
    "NOT" gtnot_expr | gtand_expr
  end

  rule gtnot_expr
    parens_expr | identifier
  end

  rule parens_expr
    "(" expr ")"
  end

  rule identifier
    ws* [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ws*
  end

  rule ws
    [ ]
  end

  rule comment_to_eol
    "#" [^\n]*
  end
end
```

The important things are in the rule `expr` and the rule `or_expr`. I've altered `or_expr` so it matches everything except a comment. If I stick with the current `expr` rule I get a stack overflow. But if I switch it so it doesn't have the choice between or_expr and gtor_expr it works fine.

My understanding of the "choice" is that it will try to evaluate them in order. If the first choice *fails*, then it will try the second. In this case, the first choice is obviously capable of succeeding, so why do I get a stack overflow if I include a second choice that should never be taken?

Comment: At first glance, it appears that the `gtor_expr` depends on `and_expr` which depends on `gtor_expr`. Infinite loop.

Comment: @MarkThomas I know it seems strange. I'm basing it off of an Arithmetic Grammar from here https://github.com/mjackson/citrus/blob/master/lib/citrus/grammars/calc.citrus. In that case, notice that `term` depends on `additive` which depends on `term` again. I think it's OK because in both cases we specify that there must be a specific symbol preceding it (such as an "OR" or "AND").

Comment: I upvoted @MarkThomas but since and_expr consumes "AND" I dont't think this produces the SO.

Answer (score 1):

the loop may result because gtand_expr -> not_expr, and not_expr -> gtand_expr.

I think you can replace not_expr's rule with

```
not_expr -> "NOT" not_expr | gtnot_expr
```

And you should try simpler rules using regexp operators:

```
expr -> orexpr
orexpr -> andexpr ("OR" andexpr)*
andexpr -> notexpr ("AND" notexpr)*
notexpr -> "NOT"? atomicexpr
atomicexpr -> id | "(" expr ")"
```

Comment: use "NOT"* if you want to allow expressions with more than one consecutive not.